# Change date format and add placeholder date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Two part question, first, I have been messing around with attempting to change the `startDate` format for my calendar. I looked into how to manipulate `.toLocaleString()` but, cannot seem to reformat the date ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)).

```
<a onClick={toggleDate} className="date-picker-toggler">
  {state.startDate && state.startDate.toLocaleString()} / {state.endDate && state.endDate.toLocaleString()} 
  <i className="fal fa-calendar"></i>
</a>
```

Secondly, is there away to add a placeholder value? Currently it is null and just the "/" shows before a date is picked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.toLocaleDateString` will work if the date object is a plain js date type. You also can specify the locale (e.g. de):

```
<a onClick={toggleDate} className="date-picker-toggler">
  {state.startDate && state.endDate
    ? `${state.startDate.toLocaleDateString('de')} / ${state.endDate.toLocaleDateString('de')}`
    : 'Default value'}
  <i className="fal fa-calendar"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression displays the formatted date if you've got both a `startDate` and an `endDate`:

```
(state.startDate && state.endDate) ? (state.startDate && state.startDate.toLocaleString() / state.endDate && state.endDate.toLocaleString()) : "placeholder"
```

In the example existence of both dates is checked by `(state.startDate && state.endDate)`. When this expression is truthy the expression after the `?` will be evaluated and result in the date formatting of your choosing. Otherwise the portion after the `:` will be used as a placeholder.